# How to create a SQL function which returns a table output in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter //
create function myfunc(dnum decimal(4,0))
returns table mytable( ssn char(9), dno decimal(4,0))
return table(
    select *
    from employee
    where employee.dno=dnum)//
delimiter ;
```

> Unrecognized data type. (near "table" at position 51)

Comment: MySQL does not support the table data type.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server supports functions that return a `table` data type. MySQL is not Microsoft SQL Server. Every brand of SQL database has unique features that other brands don't support. You should read documentation on the brand you use.

Answer (score 0):

use stored procedure instead in a function. 
Like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `your_procedure`(IN dnum decimal(4,0))
BEGIN
select *
    from employee
    where employee.dno=dnum;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```